# Regex for matching a music Chord

Tags: regex, music-notation

I am trying to write a function to parse the string representation of a musical chord.

Example: C major chord -> **Cmaj** (this is what I want to parse)

Just to make it clear, a chord is made of three different parts:

- the note (C, D, E, F, G, A)
- the accidentals for that note (#, ##, b, bb)
- the chord name

For those, music savvy, I am not considering slash chords (on purpose).

The below function is almost working. However it still doesn't work for the following case:

- "C#maj"  # matches and should
- "C#maj7" # matches and should
- "C#maj2" # **mathches and shouldn't**

I suppose that if I could make the `chords` regex part forced to be at the end of the regex, did the trick. I have tried using the `$` both before and after this String but it didn't work.

Any idea? Thanks.

```
public static void regex(String chord) {                
    String notes = "^[CDEFGAB]";
    String accidentals = "[#|##|b|bb]";
    String chords = "[maj7|maj|min7|min|sus2]";
    String regex = notes + accidentals + chords; 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(chord);
    System.out.println("regex is " + regex);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        int i = matcher.start();
        int j = matcher.end();
        System.out.println("i:" + i + " j:" + j);           
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("no match!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The pattern between `C#maj2` and `C#maj7` is identical (C#maj\d), so differentiating between them is not really a job for regex. I would grab all instances of that pattern and then use some more string patterns to validate. You could however build a regex that includes all accepted digits as literals.

Comment: I would make static collections containing all possible chords. Than see if the string representation is found in the Collections.

Comment: "...For those, music savvy, I am not considering slash chords..."
Just for the record: You are ignoring *most* chords, not just slash chords.

Comment: Yes, you're right. What I meant was that I have no intention of adding matching for slash chords and that would imply that I had to change the regex structure itself. I have intention of adding more chords to the `chords` String. I just didn't did that for the sake of clarirty.

Comment: No worries, I just had my little weekly pedantic moment :)
There are various "dialects" for chord notation (and dialects within them) , and you can even more or less just mix'n'match parts between dialects. Musicians (with a theoretical background at least) across the world will understand any combination, but it's almost impossible to come up with a *simple* computerized matching algorithm that can do the same. (I've been there ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `[` and `]` to `(` and `)` in the following lines:

```
String accidentals = "(#|##|b|bb)";
String chords = "(maj7|maj|min7|min|sus2)";
```

Otherwise you're just making character classes, so `[maj7|maj|min7|min|sus2]` simply matches on the letter `m`.

I'm guessing you also want to add an ending anchor `$`? I see you had problems with that before, but that's probably because of the aforementioned issue.

---

Also, might you want `(#|##|b|bb)` to be optional (i.e., with `?`: `(#|##|b|bb)?`)?

Answer (score 2):

Forgive the JavaScript, but on a purely REGEX point, this pattern seems to work. You didn't stipulate which numbers are allowed after which chord names but I've assumed 2 is allowed only after 'sus' and 7 only after 'min' and 'maj'.

```
var chords = "C#maj7 C##maj Bbmaj7 Abmin2 Cbmin Dsus";
var valid_chords = chords.match(/\b[CDEFGAB](?:#{1,2}|b{1,2})?(?:maj7?|min7?|sus2?)\b/g);
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on Wiseguy's answer, I improved your regex matching. I had to add `#` outside of the variable `accidentals` since `\b` throws matching `#` off.

**Bonus**: It even matches chords like Dsus9, D7 etc.

Forgive the JavaScript, but this is the code I ended up using:

```js
var notes = "[CDEFGAB]",
  accidentals = "(b|bb)?",
  chords = "(m|maj7|maj|min7|min|sus)?",
  suspends = "(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)?",
  sharp = "(#)?",
  regex = new RegExp("\\b" + notes + accidentals + chords + suspends + "\\b" + sharp, "g");

var matched_chords = "A# is a chord, Bb is a chord. But H isn't".match(regex);

console.log(matched_chords);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Amit's post.

This is what I used for this. The important thing is to check for 'maj' and 'min' before 'm' otherwise there will be false matches on chords like C#m. Technically this would allow for chords like C#9000, but I'm guessing that won't be much of a problem in your case.

```
[A-G](b|#)?(maj|min|m|M|\+|-|dim|aug)?[0-9]*(sus)?[0-9]*(\/[A-G](b|#)?)?
```