# Parsing chords with regular expressions

Tags: python, parsing

I want to parse chord names using regular expressions in python. The following code matches only chords like G#m

```
chord_regex = "(?P<chord>[A-G])(?P<accidental>#|b)?(?P<additional>m?)"
```

How am I able to also match chords with the shape Gm#? Can the above regex be altered to also match these types of chords?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229080/regex-for-matching-a-music-chord

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229597/music-chord-regex and http://regexadvice.com/forums/thread/20327.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but none of the link answer my question. I have a very specific question, i.e. how do I change the above regexp to cover both cases. I'm not looking for a regexp to parse arbitrary chords, e.g. Cmaj7 or G#add9.

Comment: Surely `Gm#` is not a valid chord? It's not the `m` that's sharp, it's the `G`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I'm well aware of that. Unfortunately, I don't have control over the input I receive, i.e. I also have to handle these special cases which are indeed false chords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `{m,n}` syntax to specify `m=0` to `n=2` matches of a group (where said group is either the accidental or additional), like so:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = "(?P<chord>[A-G])((?P<accidental>#|b)|(?P<additional>m)){0,2}"
>>> re.match(regex, "Gm").groupdict()
{'chord': 'G', 'additional': 'm', 'accidental': None}
>>> re.match(regex, "G").groupdict()
{'chord': 'G', 'additional': None, 'accidental': None}
>>> re.match(regex, "G#m").groupdict()
{'chord': 'G', 'additional': 'm', 'accidental': '#'}
>>> re.match(regex, "Gm#").groupdict()
{'chord': 'G', 'additional': 'm', 'accidental': '#'}
```